# Error al recorrer datos de firebase realtime

Tags: java, android, firebase

Estoy tratando de recuperar los datos descripción y precio de la siguiente estructura de datos en firebase.

```
factura
    -MYphEANzwJ4o0uIhpRO
             -MYphIADv0eSYUw_furL
                           descripcion: "pollo"
                           estado: true
                           precio: 15000
```

Este es el código que estoy usando para hacerlo

```
 itemFactura.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    int cantidad = 0;

                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        if(Boolean.parseBoolean(snapshot.child("estado").getValue().toString())){
                                    ArrayList<String> elementos = new ArrayList<String>();
                                    elementos.add(snapshot.child("descripcion").getValue().toString());
                                    elementos.add(snapshot.child("precio").getValue().toString());
                                    tabla.agregarFilaTabla(elementos);
                                    cantidad = Integer.parseInt(snapshot.child("precio").getValue().toString()) + cantidad;
                        }
                    }
                    cantidadTotal.setText(String.valueOf(cantidad));
                }

            }
```

Pero no encuentra los elementos.

Comment: ¿Qué es `itemFactura` y cómo creas esa referencia?

Comment: Es la referencia a la base de datos
`FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");`

Comment: Ya, pero tienes que poner estas referencias para acceder a los datos: `factura >  -MYphEANzwJ4o0uIhpRO > -MYphIADv0eSYUw_furL` Firebase es una estructura de datos y tienes que decirle dónde están los datos a los que quieres acceder, ¿de qué modo se lo dices?

Comment: Necesito obtener todas las referencias, no puedo indicar los datos por su key, lo que hago en el DataSnapshot es tratar de recuperar la información regresando y filtrando los datos

Comment: El nodo se llama `factura`, pero tú estás poniendo `message` en tu referencia, prueba a cambiarlo por esto: `DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("factura");` De todos modos obtener datos en masa puede ser peligroso en Firebase si no controlas tu código.